# App sandbox container migration doesn't work

Tags: macos, cocoa, app-store, sandbox

I am migrating an existing Mac App Store application to the sandbox model. I need to migrate user's directory from Application Support to the sandboxed location.

I created `container-migration.plist` per the [Sandbox migration guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/MigratingALegacyApp/MigratingAnAppToASandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH6-SW1).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Move</key>
    <array>
        <string>${ApplicationSupport}/MyApp</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Problem is that the migration doesn't work consistently. The application's `com.mycompany.myapp.plist` is **always copied** to the container but the user data specified in `container-migration.plist` isn't. It sporadically worked a few times but I am not able to consistently reproduce it.

I followed the guide to the letter, making sure each time I delete the newly created container `/Users/user/Library/Containers/com.mycompany.myapp` and that `/Users/user/Library/MyApp` is in place and contains the data to be migrated.

System log doesn't contain any messages to indicate what the problem may be.

I don't understand what am I doing wrong, if at all. Does anyone have any idea what else can it be?

Comment: i am also facing same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: That was over 5 years and I really can't remember how I got around this. My app's commit history doesn't mention this either. Sorry.